# Makefile pattern rules cannot expand into directory with wildcards

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to use make to build a set of markdown documents from specific and shared files.

```
PKGS := foo bar baz app
DEFAULT := DEPENDENCIES.md RULES.md

BUILD := .build
VPATH := .:packages

$(BUILD)/%.history.md: $(DEFAULT) $(wildcard %/RULES.*.md) $(foreach f,$(DEFAULT),%/$(f))
        echo "!! BUILDING NOW $@"
        echo $^
        echo
```

with the following directory structure:

```
.
├── ABSTRACT.md
├── DEPENDENCIES.md
├── IMPLEMENTATION.md
├── Makefile
├── packages
│   ├── foo
│   │   ├── ABSTRACT.md
│   │   ├── DEPENDENCIES.md
│   │   ├── IMPLEMENTATION.md
│   │   ├── RULES.0.md -> ../COMMON.md
│   │   └── RULES.md
│   ├── COMMON.md
│   ├── bar
│   │   ├── ABSTRACT.md
│   │   ├── DEPENDENCIES.md
│   │   ├── IMPLEMENTATION.md
│   │   └── RULES.md
│   ├── baz
│   │   ├── ABSTRACT.md
│   │   ├── DEPENDENCIES.md
│   │   ├── IMPLEMENTATION.md
│   │   └── RULES.md
│   └── app
│       ├── ABSTRACT.md
│       ├── DEPENDENCIES.md
│       ├── IMPLEMENTATION.md
│       ├── RULES.0.md -> ../COMMON.md
│       └── RULES.md
└── RULES.md
```

However, `$(wildcard %/RULES.*.md)` always seems to expand into an empty list.

When executing `make .build/foo.history.md` I expected it to evaluate the prerequisites as `DEPENDENCIES.md RULES.md packages/foo/RULES.0.md packages/foo/DEPENDENCIES.md packages/foo/RULES.md` but instead I see this:

```
make .build/foo.history.md
echo "!! BUILDING NOW .build/foo.history.md"
!! BUILDING NOW .build/foo.history.md
echo DEPENDENCIES.md RULES.md packages/foo/DEPENDENCIES.md packages/foo/RULES.md
DEPENDENCIES.md RULES.md packages/foo/DEPENDENCIES.md packages/foo/RULES.md
echo
```

I've also tried adding some extra targets to better understand the process:

```
# Pattern rule with `%` as a directory clearly works.
%.static: %/RULES.0.md
        echo $@ -> $^

%.semi: %/RULES.*.md
        echo $@ -> $^

%.x: $(wildcard packages/%/RULES.*.md)
        echo $@ -> $^

# Wildcards using * also clear work.
app.y: $(wildcard packages/app/RULES.*.md)
        echo $@ -> $^

# Combination of both fails.
# I expect that if the target is `foo.z` for the prerequisites to expand into `foo/RULES.*.md`,
# searching within the VPATH.
%.z: $(wildcard %/RULES.*.md)
        echo $@ -> $^
```

Which results in this:

```
$ make app.static --just-print
echo app.static -> packages/app/RULES.0.md
$ make app.semi --just-print
make: *** No rule to make target 'app.semi'.  Stop.
$ make app.x --just-print
echo app.x ->
$ make app.y --just-print
echo app.y -> packages/app/RULES.0.md
$ make app.z --just-print
echo app.z ->
```

I've also tried using `.SECONDEXPANSION`, but I couldn't get it to work with that either and I keep seeing other people recommending against it.

Additionally, it **does** work for `$(foreach f,$(DEFAULT),%/$(f))` expanding correctly into `packages/app/DEPENDENCIES.md packages/app/RULES.md` which adds confusion as to why it doesn't work in `$(wildcard)`.

Comment: Addition to the nice answer by Beta: `$(foreach f,$(DEFAULT),%/$(f))` works because it expands as `%/DEPENDENCIES.md %/RULES.md` while `$(wildcard %/RULES.*.md)` expands as the empty string because you don't have files named `RULES.*.md` in a directory literally named `%`. This is why you need second expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The high-level problem is that you're trying to use too many unfamiliar tools at once. Let's take `VPATH` out of the picture for now.

The `wildcard` function will work, with secondary expansion:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(BUILD)/%.history.md: $$(wildcard packages/%/RULES.*.md)
    echo "!! BUILDING NOW $@"
    echo $^
    echo
```

Notice that we must escape the `$` in the prerequisite list with another `$`. I don't know why people advised against secondary expansion, but I see no easier way to get the effect you want.

Now about that `VPATH`. There isn't much need for it, since you want to search only one directory (`packages/`). Also, it doesn't work well with `wildcard` because `VPATH` tells Make where to look for prerequisites; it doesn't tell `wildcard` where to look for matches. And Make doesn't know *what* prerequisite to look for until after `wildcard` has done its work, which it can't because it doesn't know where to look. I advise you to do without it.